# Angular , creating new project fail

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. Successfully installed Angular by Cls, but when i create project by typing "ng new projectName". It fails. gives me this

```
$ ng new p1
CREATE p1/angular.json (3512 bytes)
CREATE p1/package.json (1306 bytes)
CREATE p1/README.md (1019 bytes)
CREATE p1/tsconfig.json (384 bytes)
CREATE p1/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE p1/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE p1/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/environments/environment.ts (631 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/index.html (289 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/tsconfig.app.json (194 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/tsconfig.spec.json (282 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (985 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE p1/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE p1/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE p1/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (298 bytes)
CREATE p1/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE p1/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
...
```

> npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a 
>   major vers
>   ion bump

I have tried `npm cache clear --force`.
Still problem persist

---

and then when i type "ng serve", it does not work it gives me -

> "Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\Users\Avvncor\Projects\p1". Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\Users\Avvncor\Projects\p1". "

Comment: That is only a warning, not a show stopper. Does the application get build to the point you can add code and run it (ng serve)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error, those are the files created in a new project. You shouldn't have any problems, comment if you do. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: ;;;; and then when i type "ng serve", it does not work it gives me - "Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Avvncor\\Projects\\p1".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\Avvncor\\Projects\\p1".
"

Comment: try the following command:

npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular

that sould install the package you are missing. Keep me updated!

Comment: ::  it worked thank you a lot. It downloaded the files "node_modules" but i couldn't commit  ng serve at first. Therefore i re did all the steps from start. And from then i didn't need explicitly execute " @angular-devkit/build-angular", it downloaded those files itself from then on. At the end i could execute the ng serve.