# Creating a New Angular Project Fails: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, angular, powershell, angular-cli

I'm new to javascript, and I want to create a new Angular project as shown in the [VS Code tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial) I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888707/angular-creating-new-project-fail) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483529/create-new-angular-project-package-install-failed) which did not help. I followed the instruction ins the VS Code tutorial exactly, I've even uninstalled/reinstalled nodejs and angular. What am I doing wrong? The only reason I can think that this is not working is that there is some compatability issue that I cannot find. Mypowershell output:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.20
@schematics/angular          8.3.20
@schematics/update           0.803.20
rxjs                         6.4.0

PS C:\Users\Path> ng new my-app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\Path>my-app'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So quick fix was I needed to be within my home directory to create the app:

`PS C:\Users\username\`

Don't know why this works.

Comment: Same scenario in my PC as well.